# Ajax file upload progress event not firing

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I am uploading a file via ajax request, by simply splitting them in to chunks.

The problem is progress event, Firefox for some reason doesn't want to fire that event, here is my code (most of the unnecessary code is removed)

```
//slice file
if(file.mozSlice){
    chunk   = file.mozSlice(startByte, endByte);
}else if(file.slice){
    chunk   = file.slice(startByte, endByte);
}else{
    chunk   = file;
    isLast  = true;
}


var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e){
    console.log('progress');
}, false);

xhr.upload.addEventListener('error', function(e){
    console.log("upload error!");
});

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        //this chunk has bee uploaded, proceed with the next one...
    }
}

xhr.open('POST', "", true);

xhr.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');//header
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');//generic stream header
xhr.send(chunk);
```

I'm sure i haven't made any big mistakes since chrome works without any problems, so there must be some Firefox related issue.

Comment: Maybe it completes so fast there is never any progress to report?

Comment: No it doesn't i have tried with large files and i can see chunks being uploaded, sometimes it takes ~3secs for the chunk to be uploaded.

Comment: The code you listed here appears to be correct, and I am not seeing any progress event notification issues in Firefox myself.  So, there is likely something you are leaving out that is causing problems in your client-side code.  Without a live example, it may be difficult to determine the exact source of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my implementation I'm adding the *progress* event *after* I call `xhr.open`, maybe that fixes it?

Try the 2nd code sample here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress does that work?

Comment: Well i have tried that and still nothing. In that example there is a note which says: `Note: You need to add the event listeners before calling open() on the request.  Otherwise the progress events will not fire.` So I think I did it the right way

Comment: The link you posted demonstrates *download* progress, not *upload* progress.

Answer (score 8):

for **Chrome**:

```
xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    console.log('progress');
}, false);
```

for **Firefox**:

```
xhr.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    console.log('progress');
}, false);
```